# ____ a benefit/externality

Tags: grammar, verbs

What verb would I use to fill in the blank?

For more context, this is the full sentence: "As with other merit goods, they _____ a benefit when consumed."

I guess you could say "they have a benefit" or "they create a benefit" or maybe even "they cause a benefit", but I was hoping that there is a more suitable verb.

Comment: Have you looked up synonyms for provide and cause?

Comment: They 'fulfil' a need. They 'provide' a benefit.

Comment: "merit good" is what needs to be looked up.  Merit goods supposedly provide positive externalities, that is, benefits beyond those to the consumer of the good.

Answer (score 1):

Offer, produce, provide, bestow, confer, and grant could all work.